# Add a calculated column to data frame based on another data frame

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames in R:

1. tvNationalSale: each row is one TV ad placement
2. workingNational: each row is total web sessions by minute

I want to add a calculated column to tvNationalSale that contains the sum of sessions in the 5 minutes prior to an ad showing.  I am using the dplyr package for basic formatting.

```
> glimpse(tvNationalSale)
Observations: 1443
Variables:
$ Sort.Date        (fctr) 5/8/2015, 5/8/2015, 5/8/2015, 5/8/2015, 5/8/2015, 5/8/2015, 5/8/2015, 5/8...
$ Before.Time      (time) 2015-08-05 06:03:00, 2015-08-05 21:12:00, 2015-08-05 08:49:00, 2015-08-05...
$ Ad.Time          (time) 2015-08-05 06:08:00, 2015-08-05 21:17:00, 2015-08-05 08:54:00, 2015-08-05...
$ After.Time       (time) 2015-08-05 06:13:00, 2015-08-05 21:22:00, 2015-08-05 08:59:00, 2015-08-05...
$ Market.Long.Desc (fctr) National, National, National, National, National, National, National, Nat...
$ Campaign.Name    (fctr) europe-sale, europe-sale, europe-sale, europe-sale, europe-sale, europe-s...

> glimpse(workingNational)
Observations: 44616
Variables:
$ date     (date) 2015-05-01, 2015-05-01, 2015-05-01, 2015-05-01, 2015-05-01, 2015-05-01, 2015-05-0...
$ hour     (fctr) 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
$ minute   (fctr) 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22,...
$ sessions (dbl) 161, 71, 65, 58, 63, 58, 56, 41, 56, 45, 58, 57, 37, 48, 37, 41, 43, 44, 36, 38, 4...
$ time     (chr) "01:01:00", "01:02:00", "01:03:00", "01:04:00", "01:05:00", "01:06:00", "01:07:00"...
$ datetime (time) 2015-05-01 01:01:00, 2015-05-01 01:02:00, 2015-05-01 01:03:00, 2015-05-01 01:04:0...
```

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190937/how-to-get-sum-of-values-every-8-days-by-date-in-data-frame-in-r) shows how to calculate period metrics within one data frame but I can't figure out how to calculate a similar metric from a separate data frame.

I tried this code which I think doesn't work because I am trying to reference a separate data frame in the mutate() command.

```
tvNationalSale <- tvNationalSale %>%
mutate(Before.Sessions=sum(filter(workingNational, datetime>=tvNationalSale$Before.Time & datetime<=tvNationalSale$Ad.Time)$sessions))
```

Any ideas on how to append calculated metrics from another data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `workingNational` data doesn't have gaps or other irregularities, you could look up the location of each ad time in `workingNational` and then just take the five entries leading up to that time:

```
indices <- match(tvNationalSale$Ad.Time, workingNational$datetime)
tvNationalSale$fiveMinutesBefore <- rowSums(sapply(1:5, function(x) workingNational$sessions[indices-x]))
head(tvNationalSale)
#               Ad.Time fiveMinutesBefore
# 1 2015-01-03 04:02:00              3126
# 2 2015-01-05 02:57:00              2221
# 3 2015-01-04 14:53:00              4269
# 4 2015-01-07 01:17:00              1916
# 5 2015-01-06 15:37:00              2484
# 6 2015-01-03 14:23:00              3092
```

Data:

```
set.seed(144)
workingNational=data.frame(datetime=seq(from=ISOdate(2015, 1, 1), to=ISOdate(2015, 1, 8), by="min"))
workingNational$sessions <- sample(1:1000, nrow(workingNational), replace=TRUE)
tvNationalSale=data.frame(Ad.Time=sample(workingNational$datetime, 100))
```