# Aggregate data by irregular time periods ("xts" library)

Tags: r, time-series, aggregate, xts

I am trying to follow this stack post over here: [How to get sum of values every 8 days by date in data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190937/how-to-get-sum-of-values-every-8-days-by-date-in-data-frame-in-r)

Does anyone know why this doesn't work?

```
library(xts)

set.seed(123)
    

    property_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,100,10)

    date_decision_made <- format(as.Date(date_decision_made), "%Y/%m/%d")
    
   other_damages_in_dollars <- rnorm(731,10,10)

final_data <- data.frame(date_decision_made, other_damages_in_dollars, property_damages_in_dollars)

    ep <- endpoints(final_data,'days',k=8)
    a = period.apply(x=final_data,ep,FUN=sum )
```

Note: for two variables, could this code work?

```
dat <- xts(cbind(final_data$property_damages_in_dollars, final_data$other_damages_in_dollars),
           as.Date(final_data$date_decision_made, '%Y/%m/%d'))
ep <- endpoints(dat,'days',k=8)
a = period.apply(x=dat,ep,FUN=sum )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a dataframe, change it to `xts` object.

```
library(xts)

dat <- xts(final_data$property_damages_in_dollars, 
           as.Date(final_data$date_decision_made, '%Y/%m/%d'))
ep <- endpoints(dat,'days',k=8)
a = period.apply(x=dat,ep,FUN=sum )
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modifying [Ronak Shah's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65164031):

```
#first variable
dat <- xts(final_data$property_damages_in_dollars, 
           as.Date(final_data$date_decision_made, '%Y/%m/%d'))
ep <- endpoints(dat,'days',k=8)
a = period.apply(x=dat,ep,FUN=sum )

#second variable
dat <- xts(final_data$other_damages_in_dollars, 
           as.Date(final_data$date_decision_made, '%Y/%m/%d'))
ep <- endpoints(dat,'days',k=8)
b = period.apply(x=dat,ep,FUN=sum )

#combine - not a very efficient way to solve this

a = data.frame(a)
b = data.frame(b)
c = cbind(a,b)
```

Comment: Can you also explain what you changed, and why?